# Why does not PredictFocus() support FocusNavigationDirection.Next?

Tags: wpf, focus

What are the reasons for `PredictFocus()` does not support `FocusNavigationDirection.Next` ?
And how can I get the element to recieve focus when TAB is hit?

Answer (score 0):

Only ***Up/Down/Left/Right*** values are supported.  ***Next, Previous, First, Last***  directions are not legal for `PredictFocus` (but they are legal for `MoveFocus`).

[FrameworkElement.PredictFocus Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.predictfocus(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Neither does this answer why `Next` is unsupported, nor does it provide an alternative solution on how to find out what is the next element that will get focused.